# How to remove this query output in doctrine?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, doctrine

when my function in codeigniter runs doctrine works fine in select and update but it outputs this query on page how to remove this.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**SELECT t0.rsvp_id AS rsvp_id1, t0.attending AS attending2, t0.name AS name3, t0.email AS email4, t0.salt AS salt5 FROM rsvp t0 WHERE t0.rsvp_id = ? array(1) { [0]=> int(10) } array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "integer" }**

**my function**

```
 function user_find()
{
    $rsvp = $this->rsvp->repository->find(10);

    $gname = $rsvp->getName();
    $sname = $rsvp->setName('John Stewarttttt');
    $sname = $rsvp->getName();
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->smarty->assign('sname', $sname);
    $this->smarty->view('home');
}
```

Comment: Doctrine doesn't seem to do this on it's own, have you tried searching the code you use for any lines that contain an echo or print?

Comment: i have checked all my code i comment different lines but it does not come from these its difficult to find out from where it come.